# Python Time Series for Multiple Input and One Output

Tags: python, time-series

My time series dataset include multiple input and one output. All variable float64, normally i can apply multiple linear regression but i can't because of timestamp :( So, what is the best method for this problem such as AR, MA, ARIMA, ARIMAX, VAR, SARIMAX, etc.?

```
-Timestamp : 8/8/2016 23:06
-output : 102.5
-i1 : 75.705162 
-i2 : 62.113856 
-i3 : 60.498154
-i4 : -1.7119
-i5 : -1.1292
-i6 : -1.0315
-i7 : 1511.6539 
-i8 : 1518.7246 
-i9 : 1589.8241
-...
```

Comment: Can you include an [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

you can use RNN_LSTM model, you can easily change the shape or size of the input and the output according to your data.